# How to simplify an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

When I append elements to an empty list, it tends to overcomplicate.

I get:

```
A = array([[1],[1],...,[1]])
```

I want:

```
A = array([1,1...,1])
```

Comment: is this numpy?  `A=A.flatten()`

Comment: If it's actually a list (and not a  numpy array) then use `extend` rather than `append`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this when you're adding elements to the list, you can use `extend` instead of `append`

Answer (score 5):

Use [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html),

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1], [1], [1]])
B = A.flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try an inner loop to append to another list:

```
A = ([[1],[4],[5]])
b = []
for x in A:
    for i in x:
     b.append(i)        
print(b)
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 5]
```